# Set daemon to use specific python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, redhat, rhel7

I've installed carbon for [Graphite](https://github.com/graphite-project) on two RHEL7 nodes. On the first one I installed all the packages, from source, using

```
/usr/bin/python3.6 setup.py install
```

This made my carbon-cache and other carbon daemons start with a python path of

```
/usr/bin/python3.6 bin/carbon-cache.py
```

I made a mistake on the next node and installed carbon as:

```
/usr/bin/python setup.py install
```

Which forced my carbon daemon to run with:

```
/usr/bin/python bin/carbon-cache.py
```

The problem is that all my required dependencies are python3 dependencies. I tried removing the carbon-* services under /etc/init.d/ and reinstalling carbon with the right python3.6 path but that hasn't changed anything.

How can I force the carbon daemons to use /usr/bin/python3.6?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future who comes across a similar issue: the solution was to shutdown the carbon daemons and completely remove all the carbon-related files. This included the files at `/opt/graphite/bin` and `/opt/graphite/lib`. Then I ran `systemctl reset-daemons` and rebooted the node. After a clean install of carbon from source (using the `/usr/bin/python3.6` executable), it picked up the right path.